# Apache htaccess RewriteRule not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For some reason, I really cannot get my .htaccess RewriteRule to work. I tried many things and did my Googling, but failed. One possible cause might be I have a pretty old Apache version (but this is out of my control). Not sure how to retrieve the version, but phpinfo() shows me "Apache API Version 20051115". It has to work on desktops, Blackberry's and iPads at least.

I want to rewrite this: http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/?id=1234
to the following: http://othersubdomain.domain.com/?id=1234
where id can be any number (I'm fine with rewriting any parameters, I'm also fine with redirecting to /folder1/?id=1234, the important part is the subdomain and the fact that the parameters are still there). Important is that I do not get an authentication pop-up (on any of the devices).

I tried the following:

```
AuthUserFile /home/user/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "This site requires a valid username and password"
AuthType Basic

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ http://othersubdomain.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [redirect=301,last]

<limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</limit>
```

The only thing that seems to get redirected correctly now on my machine is subdomain.domain.com/folder1/ (without the last / it does not work, or if I add parameters to the end, i.e., .../folder1/?id=1234 it also does not work).

I further experimented with the following:

```
AuthUserFile /home/user/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "This site requires a valid username and password"
AuthType Basic

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1
RewriteRule .* http://othersubdomain.domain.com/?%{QUERY_STRING} [redirect=301,last]

<limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</limit>
```

This redirect seems to work, but only after I give the correct authentication user/password, and that is exactly what I want to prevent.

Tips are more than welcome ...

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work (without any RewriteCond):

```
RewriteRule ^folder1(.*)$ http://othersubdomain.domain.com$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

QSA flag tell to keep query params. $1 is replaced with contents matched by ( ).

P.S. As far as I know you can use %{...} variables only in RewriteCond.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This indeed works if I provide the correct authentication, but I want it to work without getting an authentication pop-up dialog.

Comment: Try wrap Auth* directives into <FilesMatch> </FilesMatch>. This can help you turn off auth for specific URLs.

Comment: Thanks again, but I failed to make that work. Although it sounds like it should be able to fix the problem.

I found something else, however, that I'm very satisfied with. I removed the toplevel .htaccess completely. My toplevel is a Wordpress site which has its own authentication (I just enabled some authentication plugin). And I moved the .htaccess file to the subfolders where I wanted to have this.